# Como fazer um quiz de uma pagina usando javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Como fazer um quiz no JavaScript usando o checkbox ou radio do html?

Comment: Você tem alguma coisa pronta? O site é para tirar dúvidas de programação. Tem alguma dúvida?

Comment: Estou construindo ainda, mas estou com duvida de como vou fazer, mas obrigado pela ajuda. Vou tentar montar e depois posto aqui com o código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara isso é algo muito aberto, mas vou te dar algumas ideias pra você ter uma base.

**Usando somente javascript**

Você pode usar uma variável global chamada `pontos`

E com a interface ja montada você mostraria as perguntas e quando o usuário selecionasse uma resposta, você faria uma verificação no `onclick`.

esse verificação seria basicamente (se o usuário selecionou `A` e `A` é a correta, então a variável global pontos é somada com a quantidade de pontos que vale a pergunta.

ex: `pontos += 30;`

após isso a interface mostraria outra pergunta, essas perguntas poderiam estar em um array e esse array montaria a estrutura do html aonde fica a pergunta, ex:

```
//pergunta 1
array[1] = '<div><p>Pergunta1</p></div>
               <div><p>resposta A</p></div>
               <div><p>resposta B</p></div>
               <div><p>resposta C</p></div>';

//pergunta 2 
array[1] = '<div><p>Pergunta1</p></div>
               <div><p>resposta A</p></div>
               <div><p>resposta B</p></div>
               <div><p>resposta C</p></div>';
```

e no `html` você faria os eventos, quando `clickar`  no botao ok, verificar se acetou, se acertar ou errar mude o array para o próximo índice (próxima pergunta). Acaba quando o chegar no fim do array;

Quando acabasse as perguntas ele mostrava a variável pontos que seria a quantidade que você acertou

**Mas qual o problema de usar somente Javascript?**

Lembrando que seria interessante você usar uma linguagem back-end para fazer conexão com o banco de dados e armazenar seus dados.

basicamente pra ficar algo legal você vai usar CSS, JS, HTML5, um banco de dados, e uma linguagem back-end (eu recomendo o PHP).

Comment: Vlw, já me deu um norte.